# Force views to replace instead of stack

Tags: flutter

I am rendering views based on true/false. In both views I have stream listeners and the `dispose` method doesn't trigger at all. Is it because I am using a `Stack` widget? I've tried changing it to column but I am getting `Failed assertion: line 588 pos 12: 'size.isFinite': is not true.` How do I make sure both of the Gmap widgets are being disposed properly?

```
    body: Stack(children: [
              AnimatedSwitcher(
                  child: context.watch<UseAuth>().userStarted == true
                      ? const GmapStarted()
                      : const Gmap(),
                  duration: const Duration(seconds: 1)),
            ])),
```

Comment: Can you describe more about it's parent. you can try wrapping `Stack` with sizedBox

Comment: Did you tried adding keys to those widgets?